# White Site after wpdb->update

Tags: wordpress

i have some trouble to update a table in WordPress.
When i run the query there is only a white site. 
Here is my Code:

```
global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpaportfolio";
  // Felder definieren
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $alter = $_POST['alter'];
  $wpdb->update($table_name, array('name'=>$name,'palter'=>$alter), array('id'=> $result->ID));
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Check your server log file. The white page indicates that a server error has occured, but error reporting isn't enabled so it's not telling you.

Comment: Have you opened the connection to the database with - 
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','db-name','hostname'); ?

Comment: Lee: error.log is empty

Comment: @NeilKennedy you not need this in wordpress...use global $wpdb for this

Comment: go to config.php and enable debug mode. About line 80 define('WP_DEBUG', false); change false to true. define('WP_DEBUG', true); reload the page and paste the errors you got here

Comment: The query is generating some error I think!! Comment out the query and check!

Comment: @Mike WP_DEBUG is on, only white site

Comment: @DebakantMohanty ofcourse it is the query...thats my question, what is wrong with that query?

Comment: @Tobias ok, few more questions. do you at least have access to the admin? and Is the portfolio a plugin or custom post type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong syntax, this is correct:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpaportfolio";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$alter = $_POST['alter'];

$wpdb->update( 
$table_name, 
array( 
    'name' => $name,    // string
    'palter' => $alter  // string (or int for numbers)
), 
array( 'ID' => $result->ID ), 
array( 
    '%s',   // name
    '%s'    // alter as string (or %d -> alter as int)
), 
array( '%d' ) 
);
```